# Flink fish tagging

Tags: log4j, log4j2, apache-flink

I wonder if anyone has any experience with fish tagging* Flink batch runs.

> *Just as a fish can be tagged and have its movement tracked, stamping log events with a common tag or set of data elements allows the complete flow of a transaction or a request to be tracked. We call this Fish Tagging.

[source](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/thread-context.html)

Specifically, I would like to make sure that a batch ID is added to each line of the log which has anything to do with that particular batch execution. This will allow me to track batches in [Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/field-filter.html)

I don't see how using log4j's [MDC](https://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/10/log4j-mdc-mapped-diagnostic-context-what-and-why/) will would propagate through multiple Flink nodes, and using a [system property lookup](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/lookups.html) to inject an ID through VM params would not allow me to run batches concurrently (would it?)

Thanks in advance for any pointers